# Windows 8 sound volume randomly amplifies

Tags: windows-8, audio

I have this issue that has been troubling and I cannot fix it. While playing video, or MP3, or on the Internet, the sound volume randomly amplifies to max and then lowers to almost mute level. I've reinstalled the drivers, I have uninstalled the drivers, I have checked that 50% lower down the sound in the communications panel, nothing seems to work! How do I fix this?

Comment: If by "communications panel" you mean `Control Panel / Hardware and Sound / Sound / Audio properties / Communications tab` i.e. [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y5LFx.png), did you try selecting "Do nothing"? If that didn't fix it then the only other reason I know of is bad audio drivers.

Comment: Updating the drivers won't help.. Windows says that I have the best drivers for that. It's a Realtek onboard card.

I've seen in many posts around thew net that the "Do nothing" works when the volume goes down randomly, but mine peaks at MAX too! I'll try to find other drivers and see how it goes...

Comment: This is either an audio driver bug or a Windows audio code bug, so I guess that only gives you two options where you can direct your complaints to (and probably watch them fall on deaf ears).